# How to delete multiple table parts with relation and parts not?

Tags: sql

My tables looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 
(   
    first_name VARCHAR(25) key,   
    city VARCHAR(15) 
)

CREATE TABLE t2 
(   
    first_name VARCHAR(25) key,   
    city VARCHAR(15) 
)
```

I have 4 tables which all look like `t1` (`t11, t12, t13, t14`) and 4 tables that look like `t2` (`t21, t22, t23, t24`).

I want to delete all rows that have the same key between the two sets, could I do it in a single query?

I want to get a single query to do that

Comment: Why do you have so many similar tables?

Comment: One query to delete for each table

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do, but a single query can only remove records from a single table. You'll need to explain more what you're trying to achieve and why and we'll probably be able to help better.

Comment: I am building a proxy for backend databases and I need to get some sql to delete rows between two partitioned tables